# ruby inject problem, the result not same

Tags: ruby

here is the code: when calculate, something error:

```
    arr = [0.054954087385762455, 0.5093998626512432, 5.880466289995431, 0.8639141517665208, 0.2152490168404071]


      sum = arr.inject {|sum, item| sum + item}

      tmp = 0
      arr.each do |pwr|
        tmp = tmp + (pwr / sum - 0.2) ** 2
      end
      puts tmp #   0.42948006253339877



pp ( arr.inject  { |result, item| result + (item / sum - 0.2) ** 2} ) # 0.4473023458029664
```

the  result:

0.42948006253339877 != 0.4473023458029664

why ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not specifying a starting value for `inject`, so it uses the first value as the accumulator instead of `0` in your explicit code.

Do this instead:

```
arr.inject(0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

Because in the second case you don't do any operations on the first element but immediately put it into the result.

In the first computation, the explicit loop, you begin with an external sum variable initialized to zero.

To be an equivalent of the later (**inject**) code, the coded loop would need to look like this:

```
tmp = arr[0]
arr[1..-1].each do |pwr|
...
```

Comment: Yup. Fix it with starting with 0: `arr.inject(0) { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

What you want is:

`arr.inject(0){ |result, item| result + (item / sum - 0.2) ** 2}`